# Simple renaming - remove (JOB_0000_) from file name

Tags: javascript, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I work with software that generates an output files with the names: JOB_1_sample-file_20220211083122.txt in a specific folder. There are thousands of files at the same time.

The beginning of the text file is variable (JOB_1,JOB_2,JOB_3,etc).

Example: JOB_2_sample-file_20220211083122.txt, JOB_34_sample-file_20220211083122.txt, JOB_1007_sample-file_20220211083122.txt.

I need to remove the initials from the files, leaving only the 'sample' forward.
Preferably using Powershell, CMD or javascript.

Is there such a possibility?

Comment: Please share your coding attempt and where you're having difficulties

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to output those files without the prefix?

Comment: `FOR /F "tokens=1,2,* delims=_" %%G IN ('dir /a-d /b JOB_*.txt') DO ren "%%G_%%H_%%I" "%%I"`

Comment: Wait a minute. We can't rename every thing from `Sample` forward.  The date and time in the file name is the same for all the file examples you have provided.  How would you like to handle that?

Comment: According to the example I wrote, yes, it's a big problem, but the files are generated with date, hour, minutes, seconds and thousandths, so I didn't bother to make that clear in the example.  Anyway, thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: It would really be faster and easier not to need to generate these prefixes, but for that, I must open a RITM in ServiceNow through ServiceDesk, wait for the project team's clock to analyze the impact that will be generated by excluding this prefix, etc.. We're talking of a few years.. sic

Comment: Please take the [tour] like you were requested to when you joined the site. Please read [ask] a good question. You should **always** provide a [mcve] of the code you are using and any corresponding input examples.

Comment: I guess in theory if the time stamp is going out to the thousandth of a second you will have a very small probability that any of the new file names will be the same.  But it is still possible.

Comment: (theoretical - to extend @squashman comment:) `FOR /F "tokens=1,2,* delims=_" %%G IN ('dir /a-d /b JOB_*.txt') DO ren "%%G_%%H_%%I" "%%I"&if exist  "%%G_%%H_%%I" "%%I" ren  "%%G_%%H_%%I" "%%I"  "%%G_%%H_%%I" "%%~nI_%%H%%~xI"` (should append the job number to the name in case the `ren` fails (implicitly duplicate in critical portion)

Comment: I really can't understand where I should run this command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item) with a [delay-bind script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters), combined with a [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation that uses a [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) to remove the prefix of interest:

```sh
$dir = '.' # specify target dir.
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $dir -Filter *.txt |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '^JOB_\d+_' } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>